# How to get Nth string after a pipe delimiter in hive

Tags: hive

I have some a table in Hive where in I want to extract 5th component of the string from one of the columns that looks like this -

Sample data

```
john:12|doe|google|usa|google.com|newspaper - title - 1 - volume - 1234|360671191
john:34|doe|fb|usa|google.com|newspaper - title - X - volume - 1233|360671192
john:45|doe|twitter|usa|google.com|newspaper - title - Y - volume - 1232|360671193
jane:45:1323
```

I would like to parse out 5th string after the first pipe character(|). The output column would have value as  -

```
newspaper - title - 1 - volume - 1234
newspaper - title - X - volume - 1233
newspaper - title - Y - volume - 1232
jane:45:1323
```

In case the title is not present (like in record 4) , then we return the original string as is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use split function, like this:

```
with your_data as (
select stack(4,
'john:12|doe|google|usa|google.com|newspaper - title - 1 - volume - 1234|360671191',
'john:34|doe|fb|usa|google.com|newspaper - title - X - volume - 1233|360671192',
'john:45|doe|twitter|usa|google.com|newspaper - title - Y - volume - 1232|360671193',
'jane:45:1323'
) as str
)

select nvl(splitted_str[5], original_str) result
 from
(
select split(str,'\\|') splitted_str, str original_str 
  from your_data
)s;
```

Returns:

```
newspaper - title - 1 - volume - 1234   
newspaper - title - X - volume - 1233   
newspaper - title - Y - volume - 1232   
jane:45:1323
```